# laravel guzzle return iframe data with status code 200.

Tags: laravel, curl, guzzle

laravel guzzle return iframe data with status code 200

```
<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><script type="text/javascript" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3"></script></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=18&xinfo=3-4046903-0%200NNN%20RT%281512629675030%20501%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%200%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B16%288%2c881023%2c0%29%20U10000&incident_id=406002440012479652-17972015798816579&edet=16&cinfo=08000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 406002440012479652-17972015798816579</iframe></body></html>
```

But it work fine if we enter the url in browser or hit url via postman
url `https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all`

Comment: what is the issue? provide more details

Comment: I need json data or content of the url  `https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    $client = new Client();
    $api_response = $client->get('https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all');
    $responses =  $api_response->getBody(); 
    $responses = json_decode($responses, true);
    // do stuff with response
```